# Centre a responsive image with fixed height

Tags: image

I'm building a responsive site and I have an image that I'd like to have a fixed height, but as the window collapses the image remains centred as the container width decreases. I've have tried several things and I have the height fixed but the image doesn't centralise when in a view less than 100% of the image width.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```css
.container { 
    
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.container img { 
    width: auto;
    height: 550px; 
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/500x550" alt="alt" />
</div>
```

Comment: <img src="........." > is correct , not <img src="........." />

Answer (score 0):

see here your height is fixed but also responsive . i just give an example image .
add this class into your image `class="img-responsive"`

```css
.container { 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.container img { 
    height: 550px; 
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
     <img src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Miscellaneous/Cartoon%20Characters/cartoon-characters-14a.jpg" alt="alt" class="img-responsive" >
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately this does not give the required effect, as the width decreased the image becomes squashed. What I'm after is as the width decrease the image remains 100% width but centres horizontally to the container

Comment: what is your required effect , please clear me... i'll try to help you .

Comment: Thanks,

For the image to remain the same size, but as the container width reduces the image remains centred. i do have an image which ive posted above